# Why did it not work when I changed <div id="map"> to <div id="maps">? - Ionic

Tags: html, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have inserted Google Maps into my Ionic project.

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt)

Here is the code

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Then, I tried to change the 'div id' from **div id = "map" to div id = "maps"**, but then the maps did not display.

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/KVqpqv)

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="maps" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

**Javascipt:**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Coz you didn't change the `#maps` in css - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGJYwb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to update the CSS selector from

```
#map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      }
```

to

```
  #maps {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
        }
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qygjzo

Comment: Thanks, now I know what 'div id' it is. :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for obvious reasons:
 1. You need to change the class in the CSS as well, in this case, change it from #map to #maps which is already suggested by K K and secondly
 2. Method in js is still pulling the id "map" which isn't there, change it to

```
document.getElementById("maps")
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQybZY